# Custom CSS Fonts Loading Issue

Tags: css

this is a small issue that I don't know how to exactly ask, but basically what's happening is I uploaded a custom opentype font, but loading it on the site will leave an empty gap for a couple seconds before loading the actual text. I've seen a couple sites that attacked these issues by loading a local font before changing into the custom font, but I lost track of these (rare-ish) sites to find out how they do it.

How would I fix this issue? Will I have to use some form of javascript to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance! All answers appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

it`s good question  :)

Read this http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/

**And add into  or file-script**
(if you addded @font-face in your css...):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    //load fonts
    (function(){
      // if firefox 3.5+, hide content till load (or 3 seconds) to prevent FOUT
      var d = document, e = d.documentElement, s = d.createElement('style');
      if (e.style.MozTransform === ''){ // gecko 1.9.1 inference
        s.textContent = 'body{visibility:hidden}';
        var r = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        r.parentNode.insertBefore(s, r);
        function f(){ s.parentNode && s.parentNode.removeChild(s); }
        addEventListener('load',f,false);
        setTimeout(f,3000); 
      }
    })();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, @Jane ! However is there a way to replace the text with a local font rather than hiding the page/text before loading the font?

Answer (score 0):

i prevent fout creating a css file only for the font-face rules and use the link tag in the header of the page just before linking my master css file